# how I can convert a tensorflow model written in eager mode into a tensorflow lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, eager-execution

I want to convert resnet50 model (written in eager execution mode) into `tflite`. The mode implementation is provided [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/resnet50/resnet50.py) in `tensorflow`. It seems that `tflite` does not know about the block of layers (for example: `_ConvBlock`). I am getting error message:

```
ValueError: Keras layer 'class '_ConvBlock ' not supported.
```

I was wondering if you could help me by providing a simple example?
Really appreciate your help.